# How to create 3 operand calculator

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am working on a calculator project, done with 2 operand but struggling to code and solve the 3 operand calc. The problem is when I do for example, 10+10= (answer 20) works fine but 10+10+10= (also answer 20). Seems it forget the 1st variable.

Below is my code on vb2010, please advise if I miss something. Thank you.

```
Dim first As Double
Dim second As Double
Dim third As Double
Dim answer As Double
Dim process As String

Private Sub Button15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    first = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    formula.Text = first & "x"
    process = "*"
End Sub

Private Sub Button14_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
    first = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    formula.Text = first & "+"
    process = "+"
End Sub

Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    first = "0"
    second = "0"
    answer = "0"
    formula.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub Button16_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click

    If process = "+" Then
        second = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        formula.Text = first & "+" & second & "="
        answer = first + second
        TextBox1.Text = answer
    End If
    If process = "*" Then
        second = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        formula.Text = first & "x" & second & "="
        answer = first * second
        TextBox1.Text = answer
    End If
    If process = "/" Then
        second = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        formula.Text = first & "÷" & second & "="
        answer = first / second
        TextBox1.Text = answer
    End If

    If process = "-" Then
        second = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        formula.Text = first & "-" & second & "="
        answer = first - second
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
   
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    first = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    formula.Text = first & "-"
    process = "-"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    first = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    formula.Text = first & "÷"
    process = "/"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for those who checked this inquiry. I found the solution by re-writing the code and posted it on youtube to help others who possibly need it, [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZ_e7DeKIEk )

Comment: Updated the youtube  [link] ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45KAd2aD3v8&t=963s )